# UPDATE Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um site em 3 idiomas. PT-EN-ES.
O cliente cadastra sempre primeiro as informações em PT.
Depois q ele ADD os outros idiomas.

**DUVIDA:**

No painel de controle tem a opção para ADD esses outros 2 idiomas como na imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Banco de dados

```
id   |   produto_id   |   idioma
1    |   522          |   1
2    |   522          |   2
3    |   522          |   3
```

Idioma: PT = 1, EN = 2 e o ES = 3

Quando eu cadastro aparece o ID 1 que foi o que eu cadastrei.
Preciso cadastrar os outros 2.

Como fazer um select no banco para pegar o q eu cadastrei?

Produto (ID tal) com o IDIOMA (tal)

Como faço esse select USANDO PDO

E senão tiver o idioma cadastrado aparece o botão de cadastro, se tiver cadastrado, aparece um botao pra editar e o outro para excluir

Segue o codigo que eu estou usando

```
<?php if ($listar->rowCount($dados->idioma) < 2) {?>
    <td>
    <a href="painel.php?p=produtos-idiomas-cadastrar&cod=<?php echo $dados->id_produto; ?>&img=<?php echo $dados->produto_imagem; ?>&cat=<?php echo $dados->categoria; ?>&idioma=2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Cadastrar</button>
    </a>
    </td>
<?php } else {
    $listar2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE ativo = 1 AND id_produto = :cod AND idioma = 2");
    $listar2->bindParam(':cod', $cod);
    $listar2->execute();
    $dados2 = $listar2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>
    <td>
        <a href="painel.php?p=produtos-idioma-editar&cod=<?php echo $dados2->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true" title="Editar"></span></a> <a href="produtos-deletar.php?cod=<?php echo $dados2->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" title="Editar"></span></a>
    </td>
<?php } ?>
```

Faço a mesma coisa com o ES mudando apenas o `idioma para 3`.

Comment: não sei se entendi direito, mas vc ta fazendo um select pra cada idioma?? Se for isso, não seria mais fácil fazer o select primeiro com o codigo do produto, e depois com o loop em while verificar quais idiomas existem?,fazendo um tratamento do que vai ser exibido na tela?

Comment: Foi exatamente isso q eu fiz... e deu certo... vlw

Comment: Opa blz, tamo junto ^^